# Exporting C++ Classes to LLVM bitcode

Tags: llvm, clang

is there any possibility to compile a C++ class into LLVM bitcode?
Whenever I compile a class like this

```
class MyClass {
public:
MyClass {};
int i() { return 0; };
};
```

using `clang -emit-llvm -c MyClass.cpp -o MyClass.bc` the resulting bitcode file seems to be empty: `llvm-nm MyClass.bc` does not return anything.

Is there any way to make this work?

Cheers,

Manuel

Comment: All your methods are inlined (because they are defined in the class) perhaps this results in no code being generated?

Comment: Why do you think they are inlined? inlined to what?

Comment: When you put a function body in the class declaration the compiler will try to inline it.

Comment: Its inlined into nothing. Functions which are set to inline don't generate code themselves. The contents of such code is inserted into the calling code. You have no calling code so no code is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nm doesn't return anything because you're not instantiating any objects.  Your whole code is optimized out.  Add this to your code and you'll see it built:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {};
    int i() { return 0; };
    int j(int x);
};

int MyClass::j(int x) {
    return x + 2;
}
```

Now you have something to build

```
$ clang -emit-llvm -c class.cpp
$ nm class.o
---------------- T __ZN7MyClass1jEi
$ clang -emit-llvm -S class.cpp
$ cat class.s
; ModuleID = 'class.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.6.7"

%class.MyClass = type { i8 }

define i32 @_ZN7MyClass1jEi(%class.MyClass* %this, i32 %x) nounwind ssp align 2 {
  %1 = alloca %class.MyClass*, align 8
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store %class.MyClass* %this, %class.MyClass** %1, align 8
  store i32 %x, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load %class.MyClass** %1
  %4 = load i32* %2, align 4
  %5 = add nsw i32 %4, 2
  ret i32 %5
}
```

Comment: Ok, strange! But you are right, this code compiles: `class RectangularGrid {
public:
 RectangularGrid() {};
 int i();
};

int RectangularGrid::i() { return 0; };
`